# How to work with dynamic subclasses

Tags: python, inheritance, factory, factory-pattern

I am still learning python, and I'm trying to learn object classes and inheritance.

I am trying to create a script that is able to go against multiple different databases with different engines (MySQL, Oracle, and MSSQL).

I have a class named `dbremote` and several smaller classes: `MySQL`, `MSSQL`, and `ORACLE`. class `dbremote` has one internal variable: `dbtype`

Each of the smaller classes has the same functions: `test connection`, `perform query`, and `get table structure`.

What I want to do is call dbremote with the dbtype, then call functions, and have the dbremote class utilize the correct subclass to perform the action.

I am hoping someone can show me how to perform this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple factory function to create an instance of the appropriate type based on `dbtype`, then call the methods you want.

```
from xxx import MySQL, MSSQL, ...

def dbremote_factory(dbtype, *args, **kwargs):
    dbremote_cls = { cls.dbtype : cls for cls in [ MySQL, MSSQL, ... ] }[dbtype]
    return dbremote_cls(*args, **kwargs)

dbremote = dbremote_factory('mysql')
print dbremote.test_connection()
```

Comment: nice.  looks like this will work.  do I put the def inside the dbremote class? or is it outside?

Comment: In my answer it is outside. You can also make it a classmethod of course.